# Can't access MySQL without running sudo

Tags: nginx, mysql, debian, raspbian

I recently install MySQL on an ARM system (RBPI3), if I run:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mysql -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

But with sudo it connects:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mysql -u root
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 10
Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

I don't get it why I can't access the service if I am not su. This also means that for example, WordPress that is getting executed with Nginx running as WWW-DATA user can't connect to my DB. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

MariaDB on Debian/Ubuntu by default authenticates via Unix sockets and it checks the effective unix user id of the user calling `mysql`. If you don't run `mysql` as root (or with `sudo`), this fails.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

To change this back to the classic method, log into the database with `sudo` (`sudo mysql -u root`) and alter your user like this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: So is it impossible to install and run MySQL without admin rights.  MySQL needs to make a clear and final point to end the madness.